# In what two ways is ATP used in coupled reactions?

Tags: biochemistry

I already have down "A coupled reaction is when leftover energy from a reaction fuels a reaction that needs more energy. ATP can break apart to transform into something new and use the energy created by breaking a bond to fuel a reaction in need of more energy" I think that is one use but I am not sure and I still need another

Answer (score 1):

A coupled reaction is where a catabolic reaction drives an anabolic reaction, usually with ATP as an intermediary. The energy released from the first reaction allows for the formation of ATP from ADP and P. The second reaction is then driven by the hydrolysis (breakdown) of ATP, which releases energy.

[image: ATP]

So the answer to your question is: In a coupled reaction, ATP is first used to store energy from a catabolic reaction and then used to release energy for an anabolic reaction.

Answer (score 0):

Another use of ATP is [phosphorylation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorylation) of different substrates including proteins.